# Installing gems in Rails 2.2.2 and Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My company uses an old app.  I'm having trouble installing gems.  I'm trying to install activemerchant v 1.9.2.  The error I get is

```
ERROR:  Error installing activemerchant:
i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

I found that I need i18n v 0.6.11.  So I installed it.  But then when I try installing activemerchant again I get the same error.  Is there a way for it to recognize i18n v0.6.11?

There is no Gemfile, but there's this file (named utils) in my `script` folder.  I run it with `script/utils install_gems`

```
def install_gems
  system('rvm rubygems 1.3.7')
  system('gem source -a http://gems.github.com')
  { 'rails'                       => '2.2.2',
    'activemerchant'              => '1.9.2',
    'authlogic'                   => '1.3.9',
    'business_time'               => '0.3.1',
    'capistrano'                  => '2.6.0',
    'capistrano-ext'              => '1.2.1',
    'chronic'                     => '0.6.7',
    'cloudfiles'                  => '1.5.0.1',
    'crack'                       => '0.1.8',
    'currencies'                  => '0.4.0',
    'cwninja-inaction_mailer'     => '0.6',
    'datanoise-actionwebservice'  => '2.2.2',
    'echoe'                       => '3.0.2',
    'factory_girl'                => '1.2.4',
    'faker'                       => '0.3.1',
    'fastercsv'                   => '1.5.4',
    'fedex'                       => '0.0.1',
    'GData'                       => '0.0.4',
    'gibberish'                   => '1.2.1',
    'googlecharts'                => '1.5.4',
    'highline'                    => '1.5.2',
    'hoe'                         => '1.12.2',
    'holidays'                    => '1.0.5',
    'hpricot'                     => '0.8.4',
    'htmlentities'                => '4.3.1',
    'httparty'                    => '0.7.4',
    'httpclient'                  => '2.2.0.2',
    'icalendar'                   => '1.3.0',
    'javan-whenever'              => '0.3.7',
    'liquid'                      => '2.4.1',
    'mocha'                       => '0.9.5',
    'mysql'                       => '2.8.1',
    'net-ssh'                     => '2.0.22',
    'newrelic_rpm'                => '3.0.0',
    'nokogiri'                    => '1.5.0',
    'parseexcel'                  => '0.5.2',
    'prawn'                       => '0.5.0.1',
    'prawn-core'                  => '0.5.0.1',
    'prawn-layout'                => '0.2.0.1',
    'pry'                         => '0.9.9.6',
    'rake'                        => '0.8.7',
    'roo'                         => '0.9.4',
    'rspec'                       => '1.2.2',
    'rspec-rails'                 => '1.2.2',
    'rubaidh-google_analytics'    => '1.1.4',
    'rubyist-aasm'                => '2.0.5',
    'rubyzip'                     => '0.9.1',
    'savon'                       => '0.7.8',
    'serviceproxy'                => '0.2.1',
    'settingslogic'               => '2.0.3',
    'slop'                        => '1.9.1',
    'soap4r'                      => '1.5.8',
    'spreadsheet'                 => '0.7.3',
    'spreadsheet-excel'           => '0.3.5.1',
    "table_print"                 => "1.0.0",
    'thin'                        => '1.4.1',
    'thoughtbot-paperclip'        => '2.2.7',
    'thoughtbot-shoulda'          => '2.9.1',
    'will_paginate'               => '2.2.2',
    'haml'                        => '3.1.8'
  }.each do |name, version|
    system('gem install %s -v %s --no-ri --no-rdoc' % [name, version])
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're using one, could you add the contents of your Gemfile to your question?

Comment: It probably makes sense to create a `Gemfile` for this project and let bundler solve the dependencies.

Comment: does bundler work for Rails 2.2.2?

Comment: "It may work" http://bundler.io/v1.3/rails23.html